# Closing Current Tab from angularJS controller

Tags: angularjs, html

I want to close my current Tab of my Browser once some action is performed successfully.
How can I close the tab through angularJS controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

window.top.close(); worked for me it closes the current tab for me..Thanks to all who helped me..;-P

Answer (score 1):

Use [`$window.close()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window) in $window service.

Make sure you inject $window to the controller,

```
angular.module('windowExample', [])
    .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window)
```